# Build successful when deploying web application on heroku but can not view site because I get an error, please see images below

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment

[message from Heroku error log][1]

$ heroku logs --tail
Error: Cannot find module './toString'
Require stack:

- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/lodash/capitalize.js
- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-run/node_modules/cli-ux/lib/styled/table.js
- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-run/node_modules/cli-ux/lib/index.js
- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-run/lib/lib/log-displayer.js
- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-run/lib/commands/logs.js
- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/plugin.js
- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/config.js
- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/index.js
- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/index.js
- C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/bin/run
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:/Users/esraw/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/lodash/capitalize.js:1:16)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue in the past and it was pretty annoying for me as well. It seems like heroku cannot find a node module. I don't know if this would work for you, but in your .gitignore make sure you remove /node_modules. I think the issue is that heroku cannot find the node module.

Comment: So I deleted the node_module from my gitignore file. When I Heroku logs --tail error is exactly the same. Any other suggestions I can try. Keep in mind, my site works on my local host 3000. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Huh. Maybe try to reinstall the package. I don't know if that would do anything though.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `package.json` file. If you found any code under `devDependencies`. Move them under the `dependencies` section.